# React Testing Library : check if multiple elements have href

Tags: testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'd like to check if all links in a `<ul>` have a `href` attribute.

Component (uses Gatsby's `<Link>`) :

```
const DropdownMenu = ({ open }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
      {open && (
        <>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link1/">Link 1</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link2/">Link 2</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link3/">Link 3</Link>
          </li>
        </>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Rendered HTML :

```
...
        <ul
          class="dropdown-menu"
        >
          <li>
            <a
              href="/link1/"
            >
              Link 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="/link2/"
            >
              Link 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="/link3/"
            >
              Link 3
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
...
```

Test :

```
  test('links have href', () => {
    render(<DropdownMenu open={true}></DropdownMenu>)
    const listLinks = screen.getAllByRole('link')
    expect(listLinks).toHaveAttribute('href')
  })
```

Output :

```
received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has type:  array
Received has value: [<a href="/link1/">Link 1</a>, <a href="/link2/">Link 2</a> ...]
```

Is there a way (like a `map` or something) to check if all elements have correct `href` ?

I might be using the wrong approch here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, `.toHaveAttribute` should be called on an `HTMLElement`, but you called it on `listLinks` which is an array of `HTMLElement` (`HTMLElement[]`).
If you really want to test the `href` value of each link, you simply need to make your assertions in a loop :

```js
listLinks.forEach((link) => {
  expect(link).toHaveAttribute('href', expected);
});
```

I'm afraid there is no such utility method as a `map` or something for this use case.
That being said, if there is no condition to set each `to` prop to the links (like the code you shared here), I think that this test is not necessary.
What you are actually testing here is Gatsby `Link` set the correct `href` attribute to the generated link from the `to` prop that has been passed, but this is theoretically none of your business, Gatsby already makes sure it works properly.
In my humble opinion, what you should test is the logic **you** define : making sure the links are rendered if `open` prop is `true`.
The rest is for extra safety, but probably not necessary.

Comment: Absolutely ! I was struggling with the loop (and it's so basic I can't figure out why I didn't find this) but the final goal of my test will be to check if every href has trailing slashs /. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.forEach` in Jest could give false positives, use `it.each` instead